# Read dictionary object values using for loop or linq or any other approach in a faster way

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary object with a single key and a list of values (almost 400,000 values) and I want to go through the list of values and search for the required value and if it matches then I need to extract the value.

I tried to search for a value using below approaches

1. For loop
2. Linq

but I am able to search and extract the value using for loop in 800 milliseconds and using linq it takes 4 seconds to extract a value.

Using for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryObj[consumer].Count; i++)
{
    if (dictionaryObj[consumer][i].Value.Contains("XYZ value")
    {
        personTag = dictionaryObj[consumer][i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Using linq

```
var matchedValue = dictionaryObj[consumer]
                   .Where(x => x.Value.Contains(input));
Console.WriteLine(matchedValue.ToArray()[0]); (or)
Console.WriteLine(matchedValue.First());
```

Able to search and extract a single value in one sec using for loop but need to search and extract a single value in one millisecond so that I can process 400,000 records faster.

Comment: Can you change the list (I'm assuming a `List<T>` instance) into a `HashSet<T>` ?

Comment: The Linq version should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where` so it will stop when it finds a match.

Comment: @Maarten That will not help as it looks like they are doing sub-string comparisons.  I'm assuming of course that the `Value` is a `string` and not another sub list.

Comment: You should also retrieve the key-value-pair for `consumer` just a single time, so before your loop, do `var list = dictionaryObj[consumer];` and use that instance from there on.

Comment: If you need fast sub-string matching then you'll have to look at structures like a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  They add space and it takes longer to fill them but it gives faster searching.

Comment: Linq consumes huge cpu procedure calls and burns the stack on simple data structures and basic queries especially since the amount of data is important. Mostly linq to object. Use linq to object only to have code reduced, robustness and maintainability on small data. Linq is for complex data, complex processings and to go over sql. Linq can't go faster on a foreach on a big simple list or dictionary. It's up to you to choose between code smell and performance.

Comment: It sounds like your dictionary is not very useful if you only have one key. Also, 400k items in a list where you need to find specific items also sounds like a bad choice in data modeling. If you need faster lookups, you need to change your data structures.

Comment: @crashmstr, Your comment suggested me to follow a different approach which helped me in resolving the issue. Thank you all for providing your valuable inputs. I recreated dictionaryObj with multiple keys instead of single key and storing the list of values under that single key.

Comment: @SuC I'm glad that helped. Every data structure has trade-offs for insert, traversal, and lookup times, and picking the right one for your situation is key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are repeating this search many times, then it would be better to use `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Hash-set would allow you to search for an item in almost-zero time.

And this problem is unrelated to your use of dictionary, but the structure used inside of it.

In general, if you are repeating same action many times and want each run to be really fast, it is worth it to invest time in pre-building a structure that is fast to use, but might take few seconds to set up. In your case, you could create a fast lookup structure to quickly check if value in a dictionary contains specific key. And using that lookup structure would not require looping through all of the items.